# Create rules on TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, timestamp, time-series, timescaledb

How can i generate alerts about rules in TimescaleDB? I need to create a rule, and when this rule is broken i want generate a post notification. For example: i want to create a rule that verify if the average temperature in the last 5 minutes of a device D exceeds X, then I want to detect in order to be able to react. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: An important side note: words in capitalised letter means screaming. This is a no go on all internet sites.

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimescaleDB supports PostgreSQL triggers that can be configured to fire on various changes to the database.  See here: http://docs.timescale.com/using-timescaledb/schema-management#triggers

and here for PostgreSQL docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

That should provide a good starting point, but the details of averaging the temperature over a past time window, you'll have to work out depending on how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official TimescaleDB documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/alerting), **best method is to use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) and [define alert rules](https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/rules/)**

> Grafana is a great way to visualize and explore time-series data and
> has a first-class integration with TimescaleDB. Beyond data
> visualization, Grafana also provides alerting functionality to keep
> you notified of anomalies.
>
> [...]
>
> Grafana will send a message via the chosen notification channel.
> Grafana provides integration with webhooks, email and more than a
> dozen external services including Slack and PagerDuty.

You may also use other alerting tools:

- [DataDog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/postgres/)
- [Nagios](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/postgres-monitoring/)
- [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/quickstart/notification)